# Place Auto Complete for android returning result code error but has status success

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

having an issue with the return from `onActivityResult`. I receive this result and the result code is ERROR with the value of 2 from the `PlaceAutoComplete` constant. The status object obtained method `isSuccess` returns the value `true` however. This doesn't make sense. Also, it seems odd that upon selecting the option from the list of predicted address that it could possibly fail at that point. Clarification definitely needed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please show us some of your code - your question is pretty vague as it is right now.